# In which countries (or states) can a traveler smoke weed and not face any legal charges?

Tags: legal, drugs

According to the accepted answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/is-weed-still-legal-for-tourists-in-amsterdam) tourists cannot smoke weed anymore in *coffee shops*, in Amsterdam. It is allowed only for residents. It also seems that [smoking weed in Prague](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13580/is-it-legal-to-smoke-weed-in-prague) is not tolerated. On the other way, it seems to be legal to [smoke it in Colorado](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22957/is-smoking-weed-legal-or-just-tolerated-in-colorado).

I want to know if there are other countries (or states) in the world where a traveler can smoke weed and not face any legal charges. Consider, for the sake of this question, it is ok if there are restrictions that an ordinary traveler can fulfill like being allowed to smoke only in specific places and not in public. If the restrictions are a bit harder, like having some health condition (or a doctor's prescription) or having some resident obtain the herb and give it to you, than it's not a good answer to this question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cannabis_by_country

Comment: In the Netherlands the situation is a little more complex. After a lot of back and forth, the law now requires patrons to prove they are residents (in place of the club concept) but I think most cities in the north and west of the country (and by extension the “coffeeshops”) do not actively enforce it.

Comment: Pot is not *legal* in Colorado per se; it is *decriminalized*, a judicial contortion required because not only is cannabis still illegal under U.S. federal law, it is also banned by an international multilateral treaty which, having been ratified, has constitutional force. Colorado won't expend its own resources prosecuting use, possession, etc. of cannabis, but that doesn't stop anyone at the federal level (FBI, DEA, etc.). It will be especially interesting to see how the interaction plays out with a new White House administration in 2017.

Comment: @choster - the distinction between decriminalization and legalization has nothing to do with Federalism.  [Decriminalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decriminalization) is the abolition of _criminal_ penalties; other legal disabilities may remain.  Also, in the US, treaties do not have constitutional force; like all Federal laws, they are superior to state laws and state constitutions, but for obvious reasons, they are still inferior to the US Constitution.

Comment: Asking for a list this way is too broad, you're going to get say, 50 answers with 'oh x country is too!' and 'y country legalised it in 2006' and neither answer completely answers the question. It's best to change to say, is there a resource that shows all the places where it's legal / decriminalized , so that one answer providing that will correctly answer it for everyone, AND will stay up to date as things change.

Comment: @MarkMayo, I didn't think there could be too many answers for this question, but I agree that any good answer today is likely to change in the (near?) future. I'll try to rephrase the question to better address these issues, Ok?

Comment: @gmauch sure man, all you do is edit it and click 'reopen' or vote to reopen or whatever the button is. It then goes into the review queue and whoever in the community looks at it votes on it, usually takes less than a few hours if they approve the changes, longer if not...

Answer (score 3):

Marijuana appears to be freely available for tourists in [**North Korea**](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/08/marijuana-in-north-korea_n_4067341.html) and surprisingly this appears to be the [only country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_cannabis_by_country) where tourists can smoke anywhere without fear of prosecution.

> According to multiple reports from defectors, visitors and experts,
>   North Korea either has no law against the sale and consumption of
>   weed, or it has a law that is largely unenforced.
>
> Just last week, a 29-year-old freelance writer from England wrote an
>   account on his blog explaining how he purchased a grocery bag full of
>   weed at an indoor market in rural North Korea and smoked it with
>   impunity both at outdoor parks and monuments, as well as in
>   restaurants and bars.

Although the author later [mentioned](http://www.thebohemianblog.com/2013/11/smoking-weed-in-north-korea-critical.html) that the weed wasn't as strong as the one sold in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

[It is also legal or decriminalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_cannabis_by_country) in Washington State(US), the US Virgin Islands, Jamaica (surprisingly, only since last month), North Korea, Bangladesh, and Uruguay.

Comment: Source? References?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_cannabis_by_country), where else?

Comment: The rest of the internet? Please edit links into your answer, people often miss the comments.  It's useful as it lets people follow through and realise you missed states like Oregon, Alaska and Colorado.

Comment: Colorado is in the question; Oregon and Alaska have passed the necessary legislation, but it has not yet, I believe, come into effect.

Comment: @Malvolio, In Uruguay it is sold just for residents, not tourists. There are many newspapers sites, like http://www.eltribuno.info/uruguay-no-vendera-marihuana-turistas-n172996 that confirm this, but I could not find a *oficial* one.